# Potential energy of a hanging string of a prescribed length

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations, lagrange-multiplier

> Consider a homogeneous, flexible string of a prescribed length hanging in a vertical plane where its ends are fixed at two points P and Q. Determine the equilibrium configuration of the string by minimising the potential energy of the string under extra conditions.

I can right away say that this is an exercise I've been given to solve so I'm not looking for full solutions, just some advice on some things that are a bit confusing to me.

So, first of all we have a fixed length $\textit{l}$ of the string, so if we let $y(x)$ denote the position of the string at the $x$-coordinate $x$ on the interval $[a,b]$, we get
$$J[y] = \int_a^b \!  \sqrt{1 + y'(x)^2} \, \mathrm{d}x = l.$$
So we have a constraint that we have to consider when finding $y$. This could be done by for example using the Calculus of variations variant of Lagrange multipliers.

Now, my main problem is how to find the functional we want to minimize $I[y]$, if $y$ denotes the height of the string then the natural way to formulate the integral would be

$$I[y] = \int_a^b \!  mgy \, \mathrm{d}x.$$

But is it really that simple, how do we consider mass of a string, do we take the entire mass and just factor it out of the integral expression or should one consider small mass segments?

Comment: You need an extra term in your potential energy due to the force that keeps the string together.

Comment: @Martin That would be needed if the string was elastic. But the statement says it's of fixed length. So there is no energy term due to stretching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression 
$I[y] = \int_a^b \!  mgy \, \mathrm{d}x$
is not quite correct. For one thing,  $m$ should be replaced by *linear density* $\rho$, measured in mass per unit of length. Indeed, to get the mass of a short piece of the string, we multiply its length by $\rho$. The length is represented by $\sqrt{1+(y'(x))^2} \, \mathrm{d}x$. Thus, the correct formula is 
$$I[y] = \int_a^b \!  \rho gy \sqrt{1+(y'(x))^2} \, \mathrm{d}x$$

---

Using the Lagrange multiplier $\lambda$ to handle the constraint, you'll be working with the functional
$$
\int_a^b \!  \rho gy\sqrt{1+(y'(x))^2} \, \mathrm{d}x + \lambda \int_a^b \!  \sqrt{1 + y'(x)^2} \, \mathrm{d}x,\qquad y(a)=A, \ y(b)=B 
$$ 
If you get stuck, see [page 199 here](http://www.math.odu.edu/~jhh/ch54.PDF).